# Flask login @login_required not working

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm using flask-login to make sure users are logged in before they can access certain pages. I'm using `@login_required` on the view I want to protect, but even though I'm setting `login_user(user)` where I'm wanting to set the user, it does not let me go into my protected route (index). I'm printing out the value of my `user_login(user)` and it returns `True`. What am I doing wrong?

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    print("was in here", file=sys.stderr)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

This is the route where I set the `user_login(user)`

```
@app.route('/authenticate')
def authenticate():
    code = request.args.get('code')
    state = request.args.get('state')
    quiz_auth_response = quizlet_auth(code, state)

    g.token = quiz_auth_response['token']

    response = json.loads(make_request(quiz_auth_response['user_name']))

    try:
        user = models.User.get(models.User.username == response['username'])
        login_user(user)
    except models.DoesNotExist:
        print("does not exist", file=sys.stderr)
        user = models.User.create_user(response['username'], response['id'])
        return redirect('/index')
    else:
        login_user(user)
        print("log in user " + str(login_user(user)), file=sys.stderr)
        login_user(user)
        return redirect('/index')
```

Here is my user_loader

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    try:
        return models.User.get(models.User.id == userid)
    except models.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Here is my User model

```
sqlite_db = SqliteDatabase('sqlite.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = sqlite_db

class User(UserMixin, BaseModel):
    username = CharField(unique=True)
    quizlet_id = CharField(unique=True)
    joined_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, username, quiz_id, **kwards):

        try:
            cls.select().where(
                (cls.username == username) | (cls.quizlet_id == quiz_id)
            ).get()
        except cls.DoesNotExist:
                print("putting user in thing", file=sys.stderr)
                user = cls(username = username, quizlet_id = quiz_id)

                print(user.username)
                user.save()
                return user
        else:
            raise Exception("User with that email exists already")

    @staticmethod
    def set_password(password):

        return generate_password_hash(password.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Where is your `user_loader` callback defined?

Comment: @MattHealy in the same file as my routes. I have added it above

Comment: if you run the app in debug mode, what error are you getting?

Comment: I don't get an error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just spent the last 2 hours trying to fix this and realized that it was because off the configuration that the login_required was not working

On my local development environment, I had set

**`app.config['TESTING'] = True`**

> From the [flask-login documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_login/utils.html#login_required)
>
> If the application configuration variable **LOGIN_DISABLED** or **TESTING** is
>   set to True, the **login_required** decorator will be ignored

set it back to this and got it working

**`app.config['TESTING'] = False`**

Answer (score 28):

My problem was that the `@flask_login.login_required` decorator was above the `@app.route('<path>')` decorator, so I just replaced them and it worked

From this:

```
@flask_login.login_required
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

to this:

```
@app.route('/')
@flask_login.login_required
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: This saved me from hours of head scratching. Thank you.

Comment: Guess who scratched a whole day

Answer (score 2):

Just check if the user is logged in. There might be a cookie that the user is logged in.
I tested if it was all working by just setting the user as logged in that added a
cookie.
I just added this and got it working

```
@app.before_first_request
def init_app():
    logout_user()
```

and it worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

Is the **username** field a primary key? Assuming that you are using sql alchemy, the get() method aways look for the primary key and does not accept expressions, see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get

Try again with `user = models.User.filter_by(username=response['username'])`...

Comment: I'm using sqlite3, I've gone ahead and added my user Model

Comment: (can't edit my last comment ¬¬' ) I implemented your code using pewee ORM and the problem I was facing was because the try-excep-else was supressing an exception on `login_user()` , it was indicating a problem with needed methods on ORM for flask login.  Where is comming the user mixin? You can see my code [here](https://gist.github.com/xfilipe/75c99c68e1c630449388140f2e804b9f), hope it helps you...

Answer (score -2):

If you are using flask-login, you need to make sure that you have a function that can be used by the library to load a user based on the ID.
Something of this type:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return models.User.get(models.User.id == user_id)
```

Please read [this section](http://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works) of the docs for how to do it.

Comment: I've got the loader.  I don't believe that is the issue

Comment: The syntax is wrong here. `models.User.id == user_id` is a boolean, so you're calling `models.User.get(True)`, which doesn't help. This needs to be changed to `models.User.get(user_id`