# Flash message missing in Flask during testing?

Tags: flask

When I visit `/user/member`, I get redirected and I see the following message:

[image]

However, when I am running this code in my unittest:

```
import unittest

from portal import app
from portal.config import TestingConfig
from portal.models import db


class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.app = app
    self.app.config.from_object(TestingConfig)
    self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
    self.client = app.test_client()

    self.app_context.push()
    db.create_all()

  def tearDown(self):
    db.session.remove()
    db.drop_all()
    self.app_context.pop()


class AccessControlTest(BaseTestCase):

  def test_anon_cannot_visit_members_or_admin(self):
    u = '/user/member'
    r = self.client.get(u, follow_redirects=True)
    assert 'You must be signed in' in r.data
```

I get the error that the text is not found...

I saved rendered r.data into a browser and I am seeing that the flash message is missing:

[image]

## Why is this happening?? What could be causing this?

Comment: I wonder if this is related https://stackoverflow.com/a/41895991/1641300

Comment: how does this message gets printed?

Comment: I've isolated this even more to pinpoint to something amiss with request context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501549/flask-testing-self-app-context-push-not-working